# applying the watson lemma to an integral

Tags: asymptotics

So i thought about applying the Watson lemma to determine the asymptotic behavior of the integral
$$
I(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x(t-\ln(t))}}{(1+t^2)} dt,
$$
as $x \rightarrow \infty$.
I think it should be possible to substitute the term $t-\ln(t)$ so that we can apply the lemma. Has anyone an idea on how this could be worked out?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math Overflow. Premise: I am not the downvoter. However, I should point out that your question is better suited for our sister site [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) since this one is entirely devoted to research level mathematics Q&A, and your question is not research level.

Answer (score 1):

The first term in Watson's expansion amounts to the [saddlepoint approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddlepoint_approximation_method) (expansion of the exponent to second order around $t=1$), which gives
$$I_{sp}=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x/2)(1-t)^2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{-x}}{\sqrt{2 x}}.$$
This is quite accurate, see the plot (gold: exact; blue: saddlepoint approximation)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, it would be nice if I could  solve this with methods that I learned in class. :)